# apt-get update failed for some reason

Tags: 12.04, software-center, ppa, repository, nemo

when I run this command `sudo apt-get update` I get an error:

```
jan@janOS:~$ sudo apt-get update
E: Type 'ain' is not known on line 3 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/gwendal-lebihan-dev-cinnamon-stable-precise.list
E: The list of sources could not be read.
```

I tired to install nemo. And then this happened after I added the ppa. I can't even purge it. How can I fix this? For some reason the software center does not want to open anymore also.

Another thing when I check for updates. I get this.
[image]

Comment: it looks like you have misspelled something when adding a source....see the duplicate, it should help you fix it....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sudo sed -i 's/ ain/ main/g' /etc/apt/sources.list.d/gwendal-lebihan-dev-cinnamon-stable-precise.list; sudo apt-get update
```

I'm assuming there is a typo in the script which says ain instead of main. The above will replace any instance of ' ain' with ' main' and update.

Comment: replacing any 'ain' with 'main' could be dangerous.

Comment: Nope, read it closer, it doesn't replace 'ain' with 'main' but replaces ' ain' with ' main'. There's a space before the ain and main.

Comment: well what if there was a source that had the words ain in it?

Comment: No source would have ' ain' in it. Spaces aren't accepted in URLs.